# Maximal uniquely decodable codes

Tags: co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, coding-theory

This question is about the Kraft-McMillan inequality:

If $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are words of lengths $l_1,\ldots,l_n$ from an alphabet with $r$ letters, which form a uniquely decodable code, then
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{r^{l_i}} \leq 1. $$

(A set of words is uniquely decodable if any word in the alphabet can be broken into words from the set in at most one way.)

Let's say a uniquely decodable set of words is *maximal* if it is not possible to add another word to this set and still have it uniquely decodable. Also, let's say a uniquely decodable set of words is *sharp* if it attains equality in the McMillan inequality, i.e.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{r^{l_i}} = 1. $$

**Question.** It is obvious that sharp implies maximal. What about the converse: is every maximal uniquely decodable set sharp?

I know how to prove it if we're talking about "prefix-free" (Kraft version) instead of uniquely decodable, but I don't see how to prove this version, if it's even true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximal implies sharp, even for uniquely decodable codes.

**Proof:** If there is some sequence of letters which will never appear in the middle of a concatenation of codewords, then we can add this sequence as a codeword, and we're done.

So let us prove the theorem by contradiction. Let us assume that every codeword can appear in the middle of a concatenation of codewords, and show Kraft-McMillan holds with equality. We will break the theorem into two cases.

**Case 1:** the greatest common divisors of the lengths of the codewords is 1.
Choose $m$ large. We have $r^m$ possible sequences of length $m$, and they can all appear as interior sequences in concatenations of codewords. We would like to make them line up, so as to find $r^m$ concatenations of codewords where each of these sequences appears starting with the $C$'th letter. By number theory ([see the *Frobenius coin problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)), there is some constant $C$ so that we can arrange this independent of $m$. Let $\ell$ be the maximum codeword length. We thus have $r^m$ different sequences of length at most $m+C+\ell$, none of which is a prefix of another one, and which are all in the code. We can use these $r^m$ sequences of codewords to transmit information at rate at least $$\frac{m \log_2 r}{m+C+\ell}$$ bits per symbol.
Since $C+\ell$ is fixed, then for any $\alpha < 1$, we can find $m$ large enough so that $$\frac{m \log_2 r}{m+C+\ell} > {\alpha} \log r,$$ showing that the information transmission rate for our original codewords is $\log r$. However, if the Kraft inequality is not sharp, then there is an $\alpha<1$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{r^{\alpha \ell_i}} = 1\,.
$$
And one can show that if
this equation holds,
then the code can only transmit information at a rate of $\alpha \log r$ bits per symbol. (It's possible to check this with calculus, although if you try to derive it with calculus the equations get really ugly.)

**Case 2:** the greatest common divisors of the lengths of the codewords is $g>1$.
Consider the new code formed by replacing every $g$ letters of the original code with a new letter in an alphabet of size $r^g$. We are now in case 1, so the Kraft-McMillan inequality holds with equality.
The codeword lengths in our new code are $\ell_i/g$, so we have
$$
1 = \sum_i (r^g)^{\ell_i/g} = \sum_i r^{\ell_i},
$$
proving the theorem.